# Interface for plugins to implement in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, dll, interface

I want to implement a plug-in system in my .net application, without the use of MEF.

My application loads and creates instances of types, that are contained in the DLLs.

There is an interface (`IPluginContract`) that the main application assembly uses to load dll types, and this very same interface is used by the dll projects (the plug-ins) to implement it.

So different projects need access to the same interface.

I can realize this requirement by pushing the interface class into a separate Class Library, that both main app and the plug-ins will reference.

Is it a correct way to work around the described problem?

Comment: both the implementation plug-ins and the application will reference the interfaces DLL. It's a good idea to load the plugins into their own Application Domain.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use MEF?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not see the note that you do not want to use MEF. Deleted the answer. Yet, I still recommend it.

Comment: +1 for a great question. I'd go for MEF but it's good to know that another way is also possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, pushing your interfaces out into a shared library is a preferred solution. You then only need to distribute this library to plugin developers, which could be considered as lightweight, but the plugin will be coupled to an exact version of the interface.

Another solution is a convention based solution, where plugin writers have types that "conform" to an interface e.g. have appropriate methods on a class which they can point to via a config file. You can then use reflection, IL generation, etc, to wire this up to a concrete internal interface\proxy. The benefit here is that plugins are then not hard-wired to a specific interface version, so there is more flexibility in versioning.

You could also consider versioning by maintaining all versions of your interface e.g. IPlugin_1, IPlugin_2, etc. It's then up to plugin writers to implement whichever version, and for you to be able to handle each version.

Comment: Thank you. I am planning to allow others to develop plugins, so the approach, where I pull the methods via reflection seems very good.

Answer (score 1):

We have successfully taken two different approaches to this issue depending on the circumstances at the time (time to market, implementation difficulty, internals exposure concerns, etc):

1) Move the interface into its own DLL. This works well if the plugins don't need any other support objects/functions/data embedded in your main application DLL or if you don't want to expose public members in your main DLL to plugin writers.

2) Leave the interface in the main DLL. We have primarily used this when the refactoring cost to move the interface and associated classes was too high or when the plugins were completely self-contained (i.e. we author them for customers).